# Is "let know him" grammatical?

Tags: grammar

We usually say:

> Let *me* know.
>
> I will let *him* know.

Could the following be considered grammatical?

> I will *let know* him.
>
> *Let know* the guy.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to convey? What is the sentence expected to mean?

Comment: @Kris just want to know if it's grammatical.

Comment: @Kris: Actually someone said that the latter were also grammatical but not very common.

Comment: @Noah: Whoever told you that the latter two (*"I will let know him" and *"Let know the guy") was absolutely wrong. Barrie England's answer is absolutely correct: **Ungrammatical** because they violate the rules for that English verb. They're "uncommon" only because most non-native speakers don't make that particular error. I never read it or heard it in 40 years of teaching ESL/EFL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last two are ungrammatical because a sentence in which *let* is used with a non-finite verb such as *know* follows the pattern (Noun) + Verb + Noun + Verb.

Other verbs which cause a sentence to follow this pattern are *make, see, hear, have* (when it means *force to*), *help, know, feel, notice, observe* and *watch*.